# expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given?

Tags: php, mysql

Sorry for my bad English! Just look at the selection because the query it self is good.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysqli\_fetch\_array()/mysqli\_fetch\_assoc()/mysqli\_fetch\_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource or mysqli\_result, boolean given](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysqli-fetch-array-mysqli-fetch-assoc-mysqli-fetch-row-expects-parameter-1)

Answer (score 1):

your query is failing, try replacing this:

```
$res = mysqli_query($sql,$db)
  or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($db));
```